# T4MVC while ReSharper is on-board?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resharper, t4mvc

What are pros/cons of using T4MVC templates while ReSharper already has support for all the magic strings in MVC ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With T4MVC, you still get compile time checking with the constants. Resharper is actually smart enough to dive into constants and evaluate if name actually exists or not.